# How can I read info from .wave file using JavaSound (Java, Java Sound)

Tags: java, wav, sample, pcm, javasound

Hi I need to read SampleRate, SignalFrequency and Amplitude from .wave file. How can I do that using JavaSound?

Answer (score 5):

You can get the sampling rate by getting a handle on the `AudioFormat` object:

```
AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("test.wav"));
AudioFormat audioFormat = audioInputStream.getFormat();
```

Once you have that, you can get the sample rate as follows:

```
float sampleRate = audioFormat.getSampleRate();
```

As for the amplitude, that is basically the raw .wav file data, which you can access directly from the `audioInputStream` by calling any of its `read()` methods.